# Error while trying to generate UMDF 2.0 driver from template

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wdk, umdf

I installed Windows 10 build 10163 and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate edition on a clean machine, and then added the Windows SDK, WDK, and VSDEV12_WDK based on the specified OS version.

I'm trying to create for the first time a UMDF 2.0 driver by using
File -> New -> Project -> Template -> Visual C++ -> Windows Driver -> WDF -> User Mode V2 Empty, and receive the error below. I would appreciate any help.

`` C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\WindowsDriver.Default.props(13,5): error MSB4186: Invalid static method invocation syntax:
    "[Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::GetLatestSDKTargetPlatformVersion('Windows', '10.0')".
    Method 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper.GetLatestSDKTargetPlatformVersion' not found.
    Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)).  [D:\Workspace\
    gcp\gnssAdaptation\winAdaptation\WinPhone\64-bit\gnssDriver\gnssDriver Package\gnssDriver Package.vcxproj]
    Done Building Project "D:\Workspace\gcp\gnssAdaptation\winAdaptation\WinPhone\64-bit\gnssDriver\gnssDriver Package\gnss
    Driver Package.vcxproj" (Clean target(s)) -- FAILED. ``

Comment: Fixed some typos and grammatical errors, embedded code block.